# Use GET function to run results from a loop

Tags: r, api, url

I was trying to run the result the list of URLs in the GET

## URL criteria

```
lon <- as.list(seq(-124.4531, -68.02734, by=5.9180))
lat <- as.list(seq(25.7998, 49.0090, by=5.6667))
z <- expand.grid(lon,lat)
z <- as.data.frame(cbind("lon" = unlist(z$Var1), "lat" = unlist(z$Var2)))
n = dim(z)[1]
```

## create the list of URLs

```
for(i in 1:n) {
  for(j in 1:n) {
    URL<- paste0("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=", as.character(z$lat[j]), ",", as.character(z$lon[i]),                 "&radius=50000&name=MetroPCS&key=key")

    print(URL)
  }
}
```

## Run the list of URLs with GET function

```
loop<-function(URL){
  res<-GET("URL")
  jasonAnse<-contnet(res,"text")
  myDataframe<- jsonlite::fromJSON(content(res,"text"))
}

myDataframe
```

## Able to run all records but only the last one stored

But it seems like the GET function can only run the last record. Not sure if it is sth wrong with the loop or the GET() function.

Comment: Have you looked at the value of `URL` in between and after your double-`for`-loop? `print`-ing puts something to the console, which is really only good for a "feel-good" moment, but does nothing for the follow-on code. You need to *capture* it, perhaps by pre-allocating a large vector (not recommended) or by using something like `mapply`.

Comment: Perhaps `URL <- mapply(sprintf, list("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=%s,%s"), z[,1], z[,2])` is a start? (I realize there is much more to the string after the location, I'm just starting it here ... if you aren't familiar, check out [`?sprintf`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sprintf.html).)

Comment: @r2evans, thanks. The -mapply- works well in terms of generating the list of URLs, but the GET() loop still seems only able to run the last result. Not sure if it is sth to do the the GET() function?

Comment: Yeah, so use something like `lapply(URLs, GET)`?

Comment: More the point ... `GET` works on a single URL at a time, so you need to iterate over it. The more elegant solution is to use one of the `apply` functions (I suggest `lapply`, but there are reasons for `sapply(..., simplify=FALSE)`), but a pre-allocated list and a `for` loop could do it as well. From there, you might do `lapply(ret, function(x) fromJSON(content(x, "text")))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I see a problem that says "1 or more" of something, I tend to think about doing something once and iterating over all items in a vector or list. You started thinking in that way, but in your loop, you assign *over* `URL` each time and only save the last one. Even had you saved all of the URLs, though, `GET` only retrieves one at a time, so you need to iterate that function as well.

This demo is mostly concept with no real proof that it works. Because you included an actual API key in your question, it has been exhausted. (You probably want to delete it from the question.) Regardless, I'm somewhat confident the concept works of applying functions to a list of things, so though I haven't verified that you get a huge data.frame out of it, perhaps I'll get lucky.

```
z <- expand.grid(lon = seq(-124.4531, -68.02734, by=5.9180),
                 lat = seq(25.7998, 49.0090, by=5.6667))
head(z)
#         lon     lat
# 1 -124.4531 25.7998
# 2 -118.5351 25.7998
# 3 -112.6171 25.7998
# 4 -106.6991 25.7998
# 5 -100.7811 25.7998
# 6  -94.8631 25.7998
```

`mapply` (and `Map`) work by applying *1 or more* arguments from vectors/lists to a single function (the first argument). In some languages, it is considered "zipping up the arguments". Consider this:

```
mapply(function(x,y,z) x+y-z,
       c(1,2,3,4), c(5,6,7,8), c(9,10,11,12))
```

The first call to the anonymous function would execute `1+5-9`; second, `2+6-10`; etc. There are further tricks to using this, but looking back at your question:

```
URLs <- mapply(sprintf,
               list("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=%s,%s&radius=50000&name=MetroPCS&key=AIzaSyA3u4HwTGiUsHP7FNUKkjbYcHHe1xFBDTU"),
               z$lat, z$lon)
```

(**Edit**: I previously had `z$lat` and `z$lon` reversed within the `mapply`, fixed.)

The function `sprintf` accepts an arbitrary number of arguments: the first is always the formatting string, and the second and beyond (if any) are always the arguments/objects to fill out the formatting string. The `list("htt...")` argument just provides that argument to each call of `sprintf`, so the function calls are broken out to be:

```
sprintf("https...", z$lon[1], z$lon[2])
sprintf("https...", z$lon[2], z$lon[2])
# ...
sprintf("https...", z$lon[50], z$lon[50])
```

Those calls are wrapped back into a `character` vector, length 50.

```
(URLs <- head(URLs)) # doing this for a simpler demo, since I don't need all 50
# [1] "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=-124.4531,25.7998&radius=50000&name=MetroPCS&key=AIzaSyA3u4HwTGiUsHP7FNUKkjbYcHHe1xFBDTU"
# [2] "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=-118.5351,25.7998&radius=50000&name=MetroPCS&key=AIzaSyA3u4HwTGiUsHP7FNUKkjbYcHHe1xFBDTU"
# [3] "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=-112.6171,25.7998&radius=50000&name=MetroPCS&key=AIzaSyA3u4HwTGiUsHP7FNUKkjbYcHHe1xFBDTU"
# [4] "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=-106.6991,25.7998&radius=50000&name=MetroPCS&key=AIzaSyA3u4HwTGiUsHP7FNUKkjbYcHHe1xFBDTU"
# [5] "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=-100.7811,25.7998&radius=50000&name=MetroPCS&key=AIzaSyA3u4HwTGiUsHP7FNUKkjbYcHHe1xFBDTU"
# [6] "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=-94.8631,25.7998&radius=50000&name=MetroPCS&key=AIzaSyA3u4HwTGiUsHP7FNUKkjbYcHHe1xFBDTU"
```

We still have a list of "1 or more", so we can continue using the `lapply` logic:

```
HTMLs <- lapply(URLs, GET)
HTMLs[1]
# [[1]]
# Response [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=-124.4531,25.7998&radius=50000&name=MetroPCS]
#   Date: 2017-10-18 03:23
#   Status: 200
#   Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
#   Size: 141 B
# {
#    "error_message" : "This service requires an API key.",
#    "html_attributions" : [],
#    "results" : [],
#    "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
# }
```

In this case I get a failure (which will curtail what I can do later), but this output shows you that your `HTMLs` variable should be length 50, with each of them something like this.

Continuing, though from here on out it's untested. I'm believing that you've tested this to work with a single URL at a time.

```
contents <- lapply(HTMLs, content, "text")
myDataFrames <- lapply(contents, jsonlite::fromJSON)
```

This last one should be a list of `data.frame`s, which is great! I typically do one of two things with this: if I can easily combine (`rbind`?) them into a single `data.frame`, then I do:

```
myDataFrame <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, c(myDataFrames, list(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))
```

(The use of `stringsAsFactors` is mostly stylistic, but showing how to add arguments if you need them.)

If, however, keeping them separate is beneficial (perhaps they are not of homogenous structure), then operating on a list (repeatedly with `lapply` or related) is still quite easy.

One can justify simplifying this a bit with a single call:

```
myDataFrames <- lapply(URLs, function(u) {
  html <- GET(u)
  cont <- cont(html, "text")
  jsonlite::fromJSON(cont)
})
```

and this is not wrong. Especially during development, though, it can be beneficial to keep the intermediate lists of distinct objects.

Comment: get() in lapply doesn't work, although it shows response but the results are null. there should be geometry/location/lat info under results if the get() function works.

Comment: Are you using `get` or `GET`? they both exist, with drastically different purposes. Also, are you certain this works with a single URL (no use of `lapply`)? Just checking.

Comment: used GET, sorry was a typo. The GET works, just one e.g.: U<-"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=31.1334,-81.3071&radius=50000&name=MetroPCS&key=AIzaSyA3u4HwTGiUsHP7FNUKkjbYcHHe1xFBDTU"
res<-GET(U)
jsonAnsw<-content(res,"text")
myDataframe<- jsonlite::fromJSON(content(res,"text"))

Comment: Below is one Response, very similar to yours result, but with some more "results":
  ...Size: 1.57 kB
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 31.215321,
               "lng" : -81.48068499999999
            }
         },

Comment: Oops, swapped `z$lat` and `z$lon`, it works for me (though I "consumed" some of your daily queries), please see my edit. The first four URLs produce `"ZERO_RESULTS"`, but the fifth does include `"geometry"` and such.

Comment: Gotchat, yup the URLs works. Guess the issue now is combing the list of data.frames. Seems stringAsFactor is not working.

Comment: Yeah, from my brief look at actual data, the data is not in the right format to directly create a `data.frame`; since it's a nested list, you will need to treat it as such as come up with your own function that converts it appropriately. I don't want to consume all of your hits/day, but if you include the output in a new question, perhaps we can help with that too (since it is distinct from this question).

Comment: thanks, I just asked another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46818672/convert-nested-list-into-data-frame-with-different-column-length

Comment: Ok ... if "this question" is resolved, etiquette suggests you "accept" it with the checkmark to the left of the answer. We'll work on the other question next.

Comment: okay, just checked -- first time asking a question in stack overflow... Thank you so much for your continued help!